Efficiently Removing a Single Page from a Large Multi-page TIFF with JPEG Compression in Python
I am working with a large multi-page TIFF file that is JPEG-compressed, and I need to remove a single page from it. I am using the tifffile Python package to process the TIFF, and I already know which page I want to remove based on metadata tags associated with that page. My current approach is to read all pages, modify the target page (either by skipping or replacing it), and write the rest back to a new TIFF file.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffFile('file') as tif:
    for i, page in enumerate(tif.pages):
        if some condition with tags is true:
            # Skip the page to delete or replace with a dummy page

        image_data = page.asarray(memmap=True)  # Memory-mapped access to the page's data

        # Write the page to the output file
        writer.write(
            image_data,
            compression='jpeg',
            photometric=page.photometric,
            metadata=page.tags,
        )

However, this approach has several issues:

Memory Usage: Processing a large file consumes almost all available memory (I have 32GB of RAM, but it uses up to 28GB), which makes it unfeasible for large files.

Compression Issues: Different compression methods like LZW, ZSTD, and JPEG create files of vastly different sizes, and some are much larger than the original.

Performance: Using methods like strips or chunking leads to very slow processing, taking too long to delete a single page.

Output file size: The size of the output file with using a different compression method makes it too big! (3GB Input on JPEG to 50GB+ output on LZW)


Is there any way in Python to efficiently remove a single page from a large multi-page TIFF file without consuming too much memory or taking forever? I’ve seen some .NET packages that can delete a page in-place—does Python have a similar solution?

Arguably it might be easy enough to roll your own tool on this one -- most of the complexity in the TIFF format comes from extensions, but code just deleting a page doesn't need to know about them at all -- you can copy data without knowing how to parse it.

(That said, use IronPython rather than CPython and you can use the .net libraries you reference).

@CharlesDuffy Unfortunately, upon further inspection,  the .net libraries I mentioned do it in-place, but still load the object in memory. You are right about writing my tool, one angle I can think of it is deleting a node in a LinkedList object, on disk.

Now, what would be tricky (in, perhaps, a fun/interesting way) is minimizing disk writes by taking advantage of modern filesystems with reflink support -- you'd need to inject blank spaces in the file to make content after the edit points have the same alignment relative to block boundaries as in the original file to then be able to tell the operating system to reuse the input file's blocks at slightly different (but still boundary-aligned) positions in the output file. But if you aren't targeting systems with btrfs or XFS with modern extensions then that's all moot anyhow.
